Getting connection pool issue while initiating the HikariCp data source in an AWS batch job
I have AWS batch jobs running in AWS. These AWS batch jobs will be triggered by an event bridge rule. The source condition of the event bridge is an S3 bucket. Whenever a file is placed in the S3 bucket, it will spin up an AWS batch job. Recently, I've been having issues in batch jobs. Some batch jobs are failing with an exception

HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization ,
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed,
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException

This is happening when more files are stored in the source S3 folder. We have a compute environment to the the AWS batch job which has 8 vcpu's and each batch will use 2 vcpu's. These jobs are running in an EC2 Fargate instance. However, if 10 files are placed in the source folder of the S3 bucket, only 4 jobs will spin up and the remaining jobs will wait in a queue. Once the first four jobs ran successfully, the next 4 jobs will spin up by consuming the vcpus from the compute environment. Each job is configured with the connection pool size as 10 in an environment variable of the AWS batch job. Whenever the job is launched, these 10 connections will be set as the Maxpoolsize for that job. Can any one explain why this jobs are failing during datasource intialisation itself?
Below is my data source configuration. These URL and username and password will be fetched at run time. Do I need to make any additional configuration to the data source? If yes, what that would be and what is the use of that configuration. Here, the DB_CONNECTION_POOL (maxpoolsize will fetch from environment variables which is set on the AWS batch which is 10). Total number connections available in the database is 700 above. CPU utilization of DB also looks good it is not crossing 40-50 %.
Data source configurations:
HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(DB_CONNECTION_POOL)); 
dataSource.setMinimumIdle(5); 
dataSource.setAutoCommit(true);

Can any help on this issue?
